# Is READ_PHONE_NUMBERS permission will be impacted by a change in the Google Play policy of SMS and CALL_LOG permissions groups?

Tags: android

**ERROR Alert** – this app will be impacted by a policy change This app will be impacted by a change in the Google Play policy governing the use of SMS and CALL_LOG permissions. Apps that are not compliant may be removed from the Google Play on 9 Jan 2019.

I have removed the permission of SMS and CALL Permission group listed on Google policy link https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303 but not sure about READ_PHONE_NUMBERS.
Is this permission need to be removed? because it's still showing that error alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `READ_PHONE_NUMBERS`  is not included in changes in SMS and CALL_LOG permissions .
Here are the list of permissions which require review process

[image]

Source  https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303

Check if you have any apk in alpha or beta version , If you have any old apks which include any SMS and CALL_LOG permissions then update those with new apk with updated permissions .

Answer (score 1):

No, READ_PHONE_NUMBERS permission is allowed.

Just you have to add this in your privacy policy that why are you reading user number and you won't share it with third party.

that warning to remove app from play store takes time, in my case it took 4 days, and be sure that SMS and CALL_LOG permissions apk is undated for beta users also.